# Get the minimum employees with a given job

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have this table:

```
Name                       Null?    Type
-------------------------- -------- ------------
EMPLOYEENO                 NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
ENAME                               VARCHAR2(15)
JOB                                 VARCHAR2(15)
MGR                                 NUMBER(4)
HIREDATE                            DATE
SAL                                 NUMBER
COMM                                NUMBER
DEPTNO                              NUMBER(2).
```

I want to get the department with minimum employees who have a given job (for example all the employees with 'Analyst' job).

Can you please help me with the query?

Comment: `Count + Group by + Order by + ROWNUM`

Comment: I should give a try.

Comment: Look for all these concepts to achieve the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the key is to get the count of Employee doing particular job in each department. In below query, this is achieved by subquery. Then, we want to get the Department with minimum no. of employee doing that job so we ordered the records returned by subquery in ascending and then select the first result by using rownum = 1

`SELECT DEPTNO from (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NO_OF_EMP , DEPTNO 
FROM EMPLOYEE EMP 
WHERE EMP.JOBNAME = 'Analyst' 
GROUP BY DEPTNO 
ORDER BY NO_OF_EMP ASC )
where ROWNUM = 1;`

Comment: @TusharShimpi . . . This will not return a department that has zero analysts, which would be the minimum as I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the minimum number of such employees could be `0`, you need to be a bit clever about how you do this:

```
select d.*
from (select deptno,
             sum(case when jobname = 'Analyst' then 1 else 0 end) as numAnalysts
      from employees
      group by deptno
      order by numAnalysts asc
     ) d
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Ordering should be Ascending to get the department with minimum no of employees